# Content Security Policy Attribute Mvc - Adding Many Times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5. I wrote a small filter attribute for adding Content Security Policy to response header. Here is the code:

```
public class ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; " +
          "img-src * data:; " +
          "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; " +
          "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' " +

          "localhost:*/* " +

          "https://facebook.com " + 
          "*.facebook.com " +

          "https://facebook.net " + 
          "*.facebook.net " +

          "https://onesignal.com " +
          "*.onesignal.com " +

          "https://abtasty.com *.abtasty.com *.convertexperiments.com " + 

          "http://www.googletagmanager.com " +
          "https://www.googletagmanager.com " +

          "http://www.google-analytics.com " +
          "https://www.google-analytics.com " +

          "http://www.googleadservices.com " +
          "https://www.googleadservices.com ");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

To FilterConfig:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //...
        filters.Add(new ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

My problem is that this code is adding more than one `Content-Security-Policy` header on every request. It should run once, and add this header one time only. Am I right?

[image: CSP Header Added Too Many Times]

So what can I to fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the header in `OnResultExecuting` instead to stop redirects duplicating perhaps?

Comment: @RyanSearle Thanks for the idea. But I took same result ( filter is being called multiple times and adding Content-Security-Policy multiple...  )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this problem, you need to discover *why* your filter is being called multiple times (assuming that it is!), I've found one way that it occurs, but it may not be the same for you (attach a debugger to the first line of the filter and look at the call stack to see what's triggering it for you).

I've used the following reduced case in an otherwise empty MVC project (that has the default `HomeController` and co.) to verify that in the simplest case, the `ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute` filter only gets executed once:

```
// Truncated CSP filter
public class ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; img-src * data:; ");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

// Addition to FilterConfig.cs
filters.Add(new ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute());
```

With the code above, I only see one instance of the `Content-Security-Policy` header present, even if the `Index` action in `HomeController` is changed to:

```
return RedirectToAction("Contact");
```

Both requests show (using Fiddler), the request to `Index` returning a HTTP 302 redirect to `/Home/Contact` and both only contain one CSP header.

**How to get more than one `Content-Security-Policy` header**

[Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial).

If you are using partial views, then this could well be the cause of the duplicate headers, specifically if they're calling Controller actions to populate themselves.

By adding the following code to HomeController:

```
public ActionResult PartialContentForHome()
{
    return View("PartialContentForHome");
}
```

Creating a new partial view under Views\Shared called `PartialContentForHome.cshtml` that contains the following mark-up (for visual proof the partial view is being invoked):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h1>
    Partial!
</h1>
```

And, finally, adding `@Html.Action("PartialContentForHome", "Home")` into the view file `Views\Home\Index.cshtml`, you:

1. Get a page composed from both `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` and `Views\Shared\PartialContentForHome.cshtml`, i.e. the text "Partial!" will be shown in the page
2. Will hit a break-point that's been set on the first line of the CSP filter *twice*
3. Will see two instances of the CSP header in the response sent down to the client

**How to avoid having more than one header**

If the problem is being caused by partial views/invoking controller actions, you need to make sure that the filter regulates itself to only being executed once per request. One way to do this would be to stuff a value into the [`HttpContext.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to use as a "I've already added the header" marker, for example:

```
public class ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains(nameof(ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute)))
        {
            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; img-src * data:; ");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(nameof(ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute), string.Empty);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In this updated version of the filter, whenever it's executed it looks in `HttpContext.Items` for an entry named after itself. If one isn't present, it adds the header and then adds an entry to `HttpContext.Items` so that if it's run again, the `Content-Security-Policy` header doesn't get re-added. This will work in the *general* case to ensure that a filter isn't executed more than once per request but we can go one better for a header, specifically:

```
public class ContentSecurityPolicyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        var header = response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"];
        if (header == null)
        {
            response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src *; img-src * data:; ");
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

i.e. All we need to do is check to see if the header is in the Response's `Headers` collection, and if it is, not add it again.

Comment: Those tips help me a lot. That's why I upvote the answer. Anyway, I checked partials, they don't have "Layout=null;" So I added them. But the result is same. Also when I put a debug point I saw requests comes from different controllers. Such as HomeController, NopCommerce's CatalogController ( for site menu ), NopCommerce's WidgetController etc. I don't know what to do. I can add CSP to only web.config but I don't want to change config. Because webconfig has too many lines already. Messy... Maybe I need a different approach.

Comment: @Lost_In_Library, I don't *think*  that `Layout=null` will have any impact on whether the filter gets executed or not, your "problem" is that you've registered a filter that will execute on *all* actions, but have more than one action executing per request. I've got some thoughts on a solution / work-around which I'll add to the answer in a minute or two =)

Comment: you sir, saved my day. I love simple solutions.

Comment: @Lost_In_Library, glad I could help. Simple solutions are (nearly!) always the best ones =)